# how to solve a sqlite fts segmentation fault in python?

Tags: sqlite

def tokenize():

```
with apsw.Connection('texts.db') as connection:
    c = connection.cursor()
    fts.register_tokenizer(c, '***', fts.make_tokenizer_module(OUWordTokenizer('xyz')))
    c.execute("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS text_idx USING fts4 (id, title, book, author, date,"
              "chapter, verse, passage, link, documentType, tokenize={}".format("oulatin")+")")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO text_idx (id, title, book, author, date, chapter, verse, passage, link," ""
              "documentType) SELECT id, title, book, author, date, chapter, verse, passage,"
              "link, documentType FROM texts")
```

the above is the code which is simple enough creating the virtual table and insert into it. the following error is thrown

PS C:\Users\venka\Documents\phyllo-master\phyllo-master> docker run -it dckr_img /bin/bash

bash-4.3# python3 app.py

Segmentation fault

and also how to create multiple indices for a single table?

Comment: What is `OUWordTokenizer`? Isn't this an APSW problem?

Comment: OUWordTokenizer is a user built apsw tokenizer yes. Yes since writing this post i have realised the problem might be with apsw module. But i am still unable to solve the issue. If making mutliple indexes for the db is suggested then how do i do it?

Comment: I am the APSW author.  Neither APSW nor SQLite crash like that (see their respective test suites).  The fts module as expressed in the sample code is not part of APSW, and almost certainly where the problem lies.  You either need to provide more code/pointers sufficient for someone else to reproduce the problem, or find it yourself.  If doing it yourself you'll need to use tools like valgrind and gdb (easiest on Linux, more work on Windows).  BTW FTS5 is the current version of the FTS engine.

Comment: Thanks I used gdb but i am facing savepoint errors which i am having trouble with. I posted a follow up question in the answer section since i am having trouble editing the question itself. Please help.

Comment: Can you guys help me with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41798972/savepoint-error-with-sqlite3-in-python-gdb-and-valgrind-hung